# Error while Cordova Run Android Platform

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, batch-file

When I try this command: `cordova run android`, this error shows:

```
> Running command: cmd "/s /c
> "E:\Build\NodeJS\Coba\jimmy\platforms\android\cordova\run.bat"" ERROR:
> Error: Please install Android target: "android-22".
> 
> Hint: Open the SDK manager by running:
> C:\Users\Jimmy\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\android.BAT You will
> require:
> 1. "SDK Platform" for android-22
> 2. "Android SDK Platform-tools (latest)
> 3. "Android SDK Build-tools" (latest) ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 2 You may not
> have the required environment or OS to run this project
```

I followed the hint, but I get the same error.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really installed `android-22` but `cordova` doesn't find it,  you probably missed to add android SDK platform and tools binaries to your `PATH`.